# Problem with the http preflight header in a RESTful service using ajax and Tomcat with cors.preflight.header filter

Tags: html, ajax, tomcat, cors, preflight

I´m trying to understand the CORS filter of Tomcat but I have a problem with the cors.exposed.header. 
 How can I add a preflight header to my Restful webservice using Ajax? For example I tried the X-PINGOTHER Header.

```html
    $.ajax({         
       url : domain + "/rest/businessCards" ,
       type: 'POST',
       beforeSend: function(xhr) {xhr.setRequestHeader('content-type','application/json');},
       beforeSend: function(xhr) {xhr.setRequestHeader('X-PINGOTHER', 'pingpong');},
       dataType: "json",
       data : test,
       contentType: 'application/json',    
         [...]
   });
```

This didn´t work.
I always get the status code 403 for my OPTION preflight request from my browser.

What should I add in my web.xml file?

```html
  <filter> 
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
<init-param>
    <param-name>cors.exposed.headers</param-name>
     <param-value>Access-Control-Allow-Headers</param-value>
</init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Is my configuration right?

my example is referenced to this Page: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Preflighted_requests

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you are having CORS issues. I don't know if you are allowed to do this in the server, but I'd try to add the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` HTTP header, with value `*`. You can find more information about how to achieve this in Apache here:
https://enable-cors.org/server_apache.html

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. But this is not exactly what i am looking for. I not want to open it for all Origins. I want to limited it. That´s  why I am trying to understand and configure the different CORS filters. In detail the exposed header filter. Maybe you know something about this special filter?

Comment: AFAIK you can set different Origins, but I'm afraid I have never done it before. I think those filters should be placed for the same header: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`. In the code you posted above, you're setting filters for another  header: `Access-Control-Allow-Headers`. This might help: http://docs.motechproject.org/en/latest/deployment/CORS_Headers.html